# Powershell - Get-ADGroup of type Security for All Users

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have taken the code snipits from many sites, and almost have what I need. The only problem is I need to just return groups that are of GroupCategory Security.

I am trying to search an OU in Active Directory, return the users and then list  each Security group they are a member of, sorted by name (both user and then the groups they belong to). Output that to txt file

```
$FilePath = 'C:\'
$EndDate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$FileName = 'GroupMembership By User - ' + $EndDate + '.txt'

$Users=Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=My Accounts,DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM" | sort-object -property Name

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
$GroupMembership = ($User.memberof | foreach-object {(Get-ADGroup $_).Name ;}) -join ',';
$User.Name + ',' + $GroupMembership  #|out-file -append "$FilePath$FileName"
}

#| Where-Object {$_.GroupCategory -EQ "Security"}
```

My output is comma delimited and sorted by username on each line, but I can't seem to get the groups sorted (less important overall) nor the Group listing to exclude the Distribution groups (must have). THe last line commented out, will return just security groups, but no matter where I put it, it doesn't work or fails the command.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this then. You had the logic in a comment. I guess you were not sure where to put it. I also remove some of the redundancy in creating `$GroupMembership`

```
$Users | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMembership = $_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Where-Object{$_.GroupCategory -eq "Security"} | Sort-Object Name | Select -ExpandProperty Name
    (@($_.Name) + $GroupMembership) -join ","
} | Add-Content $FilePath$FileName
```

To try and use the pipeline without an errors I changed your `ForEach` construct. This way we can tack on the `Add-Content` at the end of the pipe.

`$GroupMembership` is populated with the output of `Get-AdGroup` and we remove the distribution groups* with your `Where-Object` clause. A simple sort and expand leaves us with just the group names.

<sup>*</sup> I have to experiment but I'm not sure how that reacts to mail enabled security groups.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. My issue was definitely with where to put my Where-Object, I kept getting errors using it no matter where it was.  I'll have to look into the mail enabled sec groups, I did not think of that, although we usually don't use them.